# Angular project not getting past preloader, until hard reload

Tags: angular, angular8

when i try redirecting to the home page, the url path changes but the preloader keeps loading and doesnt render the home page till i hard reload the page. 
when i take out the preloader, it doesnt render the page also till i hard reload the page

**My html file**

```
<div class="kt-grid__item">
                    <a (click)="home()" class="kt-login__logo">
                        <img src="./assets/media/logos/bbc.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
```

**my controller**

```
 home(){
            this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: yes i did, no errors @fredrik

Answer (score 0):

you can directly redirect your page with the anchor tag then why are you make a function like...

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="menu-icon mdi mdi-television"></i>
            <span class="menu-title">Home</span>
        </a>
```

you have to give anchor tag like this.

or

if you want to make a function and wish to redirect from there then you have to give a correct route like...

```
home(){
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    }
```

hope you get your answer.

Comment: yes i did this but i still have to hard reload the page